# Upgrading from PostGIS 2.5 to PostGIS 3.1 - calling two set returning functions in a UDF is 7x slower

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm migrating our PostGIS 2.5 stack to PostGIS 3.1. In general it's been really smooth - a few of our operations on larger geometries are much faster, and the rest of our performance is about the same. The one snag is that one of our user-defined functions is now taking 11 seconds to run, when it previously took 1.5 seconds. Here's an MWE:

```sql
-- create initial geom table of a large rectangle over Kansas & Nebraska in the US
create table _tmp1 as
select st_setsrid(st_geomfromgeojson('{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-104.4140625,37.78808138412046],[-94.74609375,37.78808138412046],[-94.74609375,42.09822241118974],[-104.4140625,42.09822241118974],[-104.4140625,37.78808138412046]]]}
'), 4326) as geom;

-- duplicate this geom into a bunch of additional rows to better compare performance
insert into _tmp1 (geom)
SELECT geom FROM _tmp1 CROSS JOIN generate_series(1,1000) as x;

-- create our MWE function- much simpler than the actual code
create or replace function st_dump_mwe(geom geometry)
  returns geometry
  language sql immutable as
$func$
      select (ST_DumpRings((ST_Dump(geom)).geom)).geom;
$func$;
```

When I call this function in PostGIS 3.1 via `select st_dump_mwe(geom) from _tmp1;`, it takes ~11 seconds. In PostGIS 2.5, it takes 1.5 seconds.

PostGIS 3.1 full version:

```
 POSTGIS="3.1.0 5e2af69" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="130" GEOS="3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 " PROJ="6.3.1" LIBXML="2.9.10" LIBJSON="0.13.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)"
```

PostGIS 2.5 full version:

```
 POSTGIS="2.5.5" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="130" GEOS="3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 " PROJ="Rel. 6.3.1, February 10th, 2020" GDAL="GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28" LIBXML="2.9.10" LIBJSON="0.13.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3" RASTER
```

Both versions are running locally on my machine in Docker and were installed with the standard `postgresql-13-postgis-3` and `postgresql-13-postgis-2.5` ubuntu packages.

Any idea what's going on here? Are these changes expected?

Finally, are there any external resources that cover potential pitfalls associated with this upgrade? I've read the v3.0 changelog but haven't been able to identify where this might originate.

Comment: Have you compared the configuration settings for the two installs?  You can see them by typing Show ALL into a pgadmin query window.  Also, have checked the output for explain analyze select st_dump_mwe(geom) from _tmp1 for both installs?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this @jgm_GIS! I've compared the configuration for both installs - they are identical (makes sense- they are built from the same Dockerfile, only changing `postgresql-13-postgis-2.5` and `postgresql-13-postgis-2.5-scripts` to postgis-3.

The query plans look very similar- here's the PostGIS 3.1:
``` 
Result  (cost=0.00..267762.77 rows=1000000 width=32) 
   ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..5262.77 rows=1000000 width=32) 
         ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..5.27 rows=1000 width=32) 
               ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) 
```

Comment: If nothing else, the actual time listed by explain analyze should be different for the two query plans.  I like to use this tool to visually display query plans and diagnose performance issues.  https://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans

Comment: Thanks for this @jgm_GIS. I'm having a hard time using the PEV tool to get at the differences between these queries. The SQL I'm running is `select st_dump_mwe(geom) from _tmp1;`, which is a simple `seq scan`. PEV doesn't show any difference between PostGIS versions except for different execution times (PostGIS 2.5: 2 s, PostGIS 3.1: 33 seconds) and costliest node (PostGIS 2.5: 279.26, PostGIS 3.1: 690.84).

Comment: I've used `SET auto_explain.log_nested_statements = ON` to log within-function statements, but am not sure how to do this with the JSON format required by PEV. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I think you have more going on than just the upgrade to 3.1.  When I run this on my older Core i5 laptop, with postgis 3.0, the execution time is 7.3 ms.  So, I would start by trying to optimize your settings.  There are many guides online for how to do this for postgres/postgis.

Comment: Secondly, to get useful information using explain, it helps to paste the function into the query.  To view the text of the query plan in pgadmin, use explain analyze select (ST_DumpRings((ST_Dump(geom)).geom)).geom from _tmp1.  To get the json for PEV, use explain (format json) select (ST_DumpRings((ST_Dump(geom)).geom)).geom from _tmp1
.  The json is in the query plan under data output.

Comment: Thanks @jgm_GIS. Agreed that this is likely an issue with my configuration. I'm able to run the same statement with Postgis3.0 on my mac easily - I think it must be something to do with running this on ubuntu in Docker.